# How to enable php_fileinfo extension in PHP?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, validation, laravel

My Laravel app can't validate uploaded images. It returns this error message:

> Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you
>   enable the php_fileinfo extension?)

[image: Laravel error message]

I know enabling php_fileinfo.dll/php_fileinfo.so at php.ini fixes it. But I don't have access to my **remote** server's php.ini file.

So I thought is there any other way to enable it? And how? Maybe I can use PHP's `ini_set()` methods? I tried using it like:

```
ini_set('extension', 'php_fileinfo.so');
```

But it doesn't work.

I also read you can override php.ini settings using .htaccess files. But how?

As Laravel's default, my .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How should you put such additionals in there?

Comment: Some shared hosts still allow a private php.ini file for this sort of thing. However, most don't, and if that applies to yours you will need to contact your support team to see if they will enable it. In most cases they won't, since the change will affect all users, and conceivably it could upset someone else's applications.

Answer (score 10):

create own `php.ini` file in root folder of your directory.

example if you are making changes on a server then it should be inside the public.html folder.

create file name php.ini it will override the settings.
just add in the file

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using WHM, go to Easy Apache, search fileinfo (In the search field), and enable it ( I found for `php5.5`, `php5.6` and `php.7.0`.

And click on "Review" left tab.

Then click on provision, and done. It works for me ( I spend 3 hours trying install/enable fileinfo)

Answer (score 3):

Go to WHM and search Easy Apache install the mentioned Profile on the WHM it resolves the issue.

[image: Screenshot of WHM]

Answer (score 1):

If you have cpanel just go to

> Select PHP Version

and search for the extension

> fileinfo

check it and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to upload images then it might help you.

```
$image_size_info = @getimagesize($filename); //surpress errors(@) if not image
if( empty($image_size_info) ) $mime_type = "";
else $mime_type = @image_type_to_mime_type( $image_size_info[2] );

//safety for all cases:
if( empty($mime_type) ) $mime_type = "";

if(  strpos($mime_type, "image/") === false  )
{
//not an Image !
} 
else 
{
  //proceed file upload
}
```

If above code doen't work then it might help you -->> https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/commit/0ec96b1104e57bfcf0e40d6169c8e203b7942b34

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file where your root is and then do this

```
php_value extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

or

```
php_admin_flag extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Comment: I tried this and put it on my .htcaccess uder Laravel's "public" directory. It doesn't work: The server returns "500 Internal Server Error". Did this work on yours? Will you elaborate more on the .htaccess file?

Answer (score -1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html/subfolder
</IfModule>

</IfModule>
subfolder is the laravel project where I want to serve my application.

php.ini file in my subfolder's root folder & for enable PHPFileinfo I write those code in php.ini file

extension=fileinfo.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```