# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_fileinfo.dll'

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, whm, fileinfo

Good morning,

I'm struggerling to understand the below error. I believe it was caused when i migrated a cPanel account from one WHM to another.

I'm currently running Laravel but my log files are repeatedly growing with the same error.

```
[02-Jun-2020 10:46:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_fileinfo.dll' (tried: /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll (/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll.so (/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Has anyone experienced this before? or no of how i can resolve it...

Regards

Ross

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable php\_fileinfo extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981576/how-to-enable-php-fileinfo-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing a library. See this related question:

[How to enable php_fileinfo extension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981576/how-to-enable-php-fileinfo-extension-in-php)

> If you have cpanel just go to
>
> > Select PHP Version
>
> and search for the extension
>
> > fileinfo
>
> check it and you're good to go.

Comment: Hello thanks for getting back to me.

I have it enabled already via WHM for PHP version 7.3. I believe what is happening here is it's being referenced elsewhere...

Comment: Hey no probs :). Have you enabled it for both the `cli` and `fpm`?