# Getting an error when creating a new laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

whenever i try to create a new project, i get this error. any ideas on what it might be?

```
  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v8.75.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.75 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.75.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\PHP7\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

Comment: the error message does state exactly whats his problem... "Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension". How about you look for a fix for that (google should direct you to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981576/how-to-enable-php-fileinfo-extension-in-php ). I dont know how you host your PHP on your machine, but as it states local disk C I believe you have full access to php.ini

Answer (score 2):

Error tells you exactly what's happening.

laravel/framework required flysystem. flysystem requires PHP's fileinfo extension.

That seems to be disabled.

As it states go to your `php.ini` file (`C:\PHP7\php.ini`), edit the `php.ini` file using notepad for example. `CTRL+F` and search for `fileinfo` (or `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` if you want to be thorough).

In front of it should be a semicolon (`;`) meaning it's commented out and therefore disabled.

Remove the semicolon and go through the steps again. Should work now.

Comment: Had already checked the php.ini and the "extension=fileinfo" was already enabled (didn't have a semicolon infront of it)

Comment: You also restarted server / rebooted PC?